# Cannot get access to HTMLCollection Item via fetch method

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, dom, fetch

I want to read the status text from the Xbox Live page ( https://support.xbox.com/de-DE/xbox-live-status ) and therefore display the text of the span class "livestatus-banner-title". Unfortunately I always get the error message TypeError for my console.log(xbox_status.item(0).innerText); => xbox_status.item is not a function

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const DOMParser = require('dom-parser');

fetch('https://support.xbox.com/de-DE/xbox-live-status')
  .then(function(response) {
    // When the page is loaded convert it to text
    return response.text()
    console.log(text);
  })
  .then(function(html) {
    // Initialize the DOM parser
    var parser = new DOMParser();

    // Parse the text
    var doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");

    // Auslesen der Xbox Live Dienste

    // Versuch Text über ID auszulesen
    /* let xbox_id = doc.getElementById("liveStatusBanner");
    console.log(xbox_id.getElementsByClassName("livestatus-banner-title")(0).innerText); */

    // Versuch Text direkt über "class" auszulesen
    let xbox_status = doc.getElementsByClassName('livestatus-banner-title ');
    console.log(xbox_status);
    console.log(xbox_status.item(0).innerText);

  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Failed to fetch page: ', err);
  });
```

Comment: Have you looked at the raw html string to see if its what you expect?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Bk6XqxXM

Answer (score 0):

`dom-parser` is a bit picky, So your first problem is that you have a trailing space in your selector

```
getElementsByClassName('livestatus-banner-title ');
```

And second [`dom-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dom-parser#node) isn't an exact copy of the browser's [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) so `getElementsByClassName` doesn't return an `HTMLCollection`
It only returns an array, and the equivalent of `xbox_status.item(0)` is to use brackets `xbox_status[0]`

Also this will return null

```
console.log(xbox_status.item(0).innerText);
```

Becuase `innerText` is undefined if you look at the documentation you'll see the implement properties

- nodeType
- nodeName
- childNodes
- firstChild
- lastChild
- parentNode
- attributes
- innerHTML
- outerHTML
- textContent

I'd suggest you use `textContent` or if the element contains other html elements and you want the markup as well use `innerHTML`